# iOS CallKit - merge VoIP call with GSM call

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit

I am using CallKit in my iOS app, I can make calls between VoIP numbers, I can put them on hold and also merge them.

I want to know if it is possible while I have a GSM call in progress (connected) and I add/answer a call from VoIP, so these calls can be merged? I'm struggling to find out why this doesn't work...

CallKit allows calls to be merged only if the calls are made by the same app/provider?

Comment: Dragos Panoiu you don't found answer about this questions ?

Comment: @AndrewSas it seems that is impossible to achieve this. Calls can be merged only if are through the same app/provider.